# An android application were i need to place display 1GB data to the users ?

Tags: android

An android application were i need to place display  1 GB data to the users , Can u please suggest me which will be most easy and fast way to display content to users ? **xml / SQLITE**

Should create tables in data base and retrieve details .

or

Should use XML text view and list view to display content .

Comment: What do you mean by 1 GB data?

Comment: Use remote data store and fetch in application in background then store in local

Comment: bible content which also includes images as well.

Comment: Use web service for it and display data in listview. You can not use SQLite for it

Comment: Okay .but due to some resource issue i am not able to use web services. @ParsaniaHardik .. Can i use XML ? will it effect application performance?

Comment: But how will you fetch data from remote server without web service?

Comment: actually just have to display content. So i thought of using XML with out any remote server.

Comment: No 1 GB data is too big for local...You must use remote server

Comment: Since 1 GB is too big to store in local device, so either if you use json or xml, there should be some service providing that xml or json to you. So anyhow you need a web service.

Comment: Okay .. Thanks @ParsaniaHardik . I'll be working as you suggested to me.

Comment: ok great and can you do one thing for me now?

Comment: Yes.. Ill sure give a try to it ?

Comment: I am making one answer to your question.Just upvote and mark as green tick to it

Comment: also upvote answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 1 GB data is too big, you must use web service to fetch data from remote server. If you use local database it will be too complex for app to handle. So just use web service and display fetched data in listview or however you like.

Answer (score 0):

it depends what holds in 1 GB data .

1. if it a textual data , then you can fetch it using services  on background thread and store the data permanently in sql-lite (if the data is not changing on the fly) so that next time when you want to display the data you can retrieve it from sql lite .
2. if it contains images as well, then
   a) call service ,
   b)  store image in phone file system 
   c) store text in sql
   d) display data from sql and file system

Please let me know if the requirement is different here.